# Хеш-код шифрование строки на md5

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Как сделать, чтобы шифрование через md5 (например) было произвольным. А то загружая картинку с одинаковым именем, шифруется одинаковый код. В итоге, загрузив один себе аватар, этот же аватар может отобразиться и у другого пользователя.

Вот скрипт для загрузки аватара:

```
<a href="http://narod.ru/disk/19236310001/upload.php.html">upload.php</a>
```

Может кто поможет, буду весьма благодарен. [:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объедините для шифрования текст картинки с именем пользователя.

Если имена повторяются, а нужна уникальность, добавьте еще и дату, например.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте уникальный формат названия картинки. К примеру, %user_id%_%img_name% . Из-за уникальности пользовательского id картинки будут называться по-разному.

Answer (score 0):

Давным давно написал я функцию для генерации уникальных имён файлов, пользуйтесь на здоровье :

```
<?php
/*
#Аргументы функции
    $ncc - количество символов в имени,
        если не указано, то используется значение
        заданное по умолчанию в переменной $dcc.
    $dir - адрес дирректории, в которой будет создан
        файл, используется только для проверки существования
        файла со сгенерированным именем, и в случае
        существования такого файла будет генерироваться
        новое имя пока оно не станет уникальным.
    $ext - расширение файла, используется при проверке
        на существование файла в директории.
#Возвращаемые значения
        имя сгенерированного файла, если была указана
        дирректория для которой создаётся файл, то это имя
        будет уникальным.
    false - если указанной директории не существует.
#
*/
function step1($cnc, $cxc) {
    #var
    $a_ale = array(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, q, p, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z);
    #func
    for ($counter=0;$counter<$cnc;$counter++) {
        $nfn1   =   rand(0, $cnc);
        $doNot  =   rand(2, 3);
        if ($nfn1 > 25) { $nfn1 = rand(0, 25); } 
        switch ($doNot) {
            case 2 :
                    $nnwordname = $nnwordname.$a_ale[$nfn1];
                    break;
            case 3 :
                    if (strlen($nfn1) > 1) { $nfn1 = rand(0, 9); }
                    $nnwordname = $nnwordname.$nfn1;
                    break;
        }
    }
    return $nnwordname.$cxc;
    $nnwordname =   '';
}
#
function makeTmpName($ncc = null, $dir = null, $ext = null) {
    //var
    $dcc    =   6;//default count chars - количество символов по умолчанию
    #log
    if (strlen($dir) >= 1) {
        if (@opendir($dir)) {
            $dex    =   'ok';
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    #
    if (strlen($ncc) >= 1 & $ncc >= 3) {
        $cnc    =   $ncc;
    } else {
    if (strlen($dcc) >= 1 & $dcc >= 3) {
        $cnc    =   $dcc;
    } else {
        $cnc    =   3;
    }
    }
    #
    if (strlen($ext) >= 1) {
        $cxc    =   '.'.$ext;
    } else {
        $cxc    =   '.';
    }
    #
    $checkThatFileName  =   step1($cnc, $cxc);
    #
    if ($dex == 'ok') {
        while (@file_exists($dir.$checkThatFileName)) {
            $checkThatFileName  =   step1($cnc, $cxc);
        }
    } else {
        $checkThatFileName  =   step1($cnc, $cxc);
    }
    $cnc = '';
    $cxc = '';
    $ext = '';
    return $checkThatFileName;
}
?>
```

Вызывать вот так : makeTmpName($ncc, $dir, $ext);
Либо ещё 1 простой вариант, это :

```
<?php
$a1 = rand(1, 9);
$a2 = rand(1, 9);
$a3 = rand(1, 9);
$a4 = rand($a1 * $a2 + $a3 * $a1);
$a5 = get_sec() + $a4;
$uniqName = md5($a5);
?>
```